# Regularity connected union of smooth sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a countable family of bounded, open connected sets with smooth boundary $S_i \subset\mathbb{R}^n$. What can be said about the regularity of the boundary of $S = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} S_i$ when $S$ is bounded and connected (in order to avoid trivial patologies as an $8$-like boundary)? Is it at least Lipschitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Every open bounded connected region is the countable union of open balls. Is the boundary of every open bounded connected region Lipschitz?